# Different mean values from mean(quantile ()) and mean() in R

Tags: r, mean, quantile

I am using the "quantile" function of R for calculating the percentiles of my dataset. But i am confused due to the different mean values returned by following commands.

```
mean(quantile(DataSet$V3, prob=c(5,50,95)/100,type=8));
```

It gives me `101.26`

```
mean(quantile(DataSet$V3,type=8));
```

It gives me `105.27`

And

```
mean(DataSet$V3);
```

It gives me `109.9`

I will be really thankful if some one could answer me that why the mean values are different in three cases.

Regards,
Zoraze

Comment: You are taking the average of the output of the `quantile()` function in the first two cases, which is not the same as taking the average of the entire column.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, i didn't think this way. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

The quantiles are obtained by first sorting the data vector in order and then dividing the data into portions, defined by `prob=` in the `quantile()` function.
Suppose the data is

```
x <- c(9,3,1,10,2)
```

Then ordering it gives

```
> sort(x)
[1]  1  2  3  9 10
```

The median has 50% of the data below and 50% above. Here the data item 3 is in the `middle' of the list (3rd from either end). You can also calculate it (for longer lists) using

```
> quantile(x)
0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
1    2    3    9   10
```

The mean obtained from `mean(x)` can also be calculated from first principles by adding up all the values and dividing by the number of values

```
> (1 + 2 + 3 + 9 + 10)/5
[1] 5
```

or using the sum function

```
> sum(x)/5
[1] 5
```

So as pointed out by the first commentor, calculating quantiles and means are completely different operations on the data. This is usually covered in any introductory level statistics text book.

Comment: Hi Slouchy, Thank you so much for your detailed answer, i knew how the quantile function is calculating the percentiles but i didn't think that mean(quantile(DataSet$V3, prob=c(5,50,95)/100,type=8)) is just returning the average/mean of (5%,50% and 95%). Thanks once again.

Comment: In R you can "unwrap" a nested series of functions, so that quantile( ... ) is the first thing, then mean( quantile( ... )) applies the mean function to the result of the quantile function. A bit like peeling an onion. This is how (reverse) polish calculators work, and was also known as "functional programming". This type of thinking is behind ultra-useful functions "apply" and "sapply" in R - so google them to understand the broad concept better.